# Trying to get JSON from opentable and output the results

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to get all restaurants from within a city (Chicago) from here: http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=chicago

When I use the following code, I just get a blank page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <pre id="demo"></pre>

    <script>

    $.getJSON('http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=chicago', function(data) {
    });

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 2);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data), null, 2);` should be inside of `function(data) {
}`

Comment: I did that, and I'm still getting a blank page, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the request to finish to work with the response. To do this, getJSON accepts a so-called "callback function" as second parameter. You just provided an empty callback function, but you have to put the part of your code that works with the result in the actual callback function, like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?city=chicago', function(data) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
});
```

Edit1: Removed the JSON.parse call as getJSON already returns an object.

Edit2: https://jsfiddle.net/cw2e9j5s/ a working example

Comment: I've just done that, and am still getting a blank page.

Comment: I just realized that getJSON actually returns a object, so you can remove the JSON.parse() call and use data as parameter to stringify.

Comment: @thewire You're welcome. May I ask you to accept the answer then?